# VS Code says a setting is "Modified elsewhere," but not in settings.json. How do I find where?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

I have a setting in Visual Studio Code that says it was "Modified elsewhere," but that modification isn't in the User or Workspace `settings.json`:

[image]

[image]

**How do I find this modification?** By that I mean, what are the possibilities? Could it be an extension? Could it be some non-`settings.json` configuration file? Could this merely mean another project modifies it in *its* Workspace settings?

I ran `$ ag --hidden --ignore-dir '.git' editor.codeActionsOnSave` in my workspace directory (from a Cygwin terminal), and found zero results. Could the modification go by a different name?

This comment may be more suitable for a VS Code feature request, but I feel like if VS Code knows enough to tell me it's been modified, it should know enough to tell me where—otherwise, how would it know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hover your mouse over the "Modified elsewhere" text and it should tell you where:

[image: tooltip for modified elsewhere]

A tooltip *should* show up as indicated in this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/153351).

> Hovering over the indicator should reveal a custom hover that notes down where else the setting has been modified.

Answer (score 2):

Timothy's answer is good (hover your mouse over the modified indicator and it'll show you where), but doesn't address another part of the question:

> By that I mean, what are the possibilities?

- Configuration has a "target" ([API docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#ConfigurationTarget))- either global, workspace, or workspace folder (if you're confused by the multiple workspace things, it's for when you're using multi-root workspaces).

  - Global settings can be set in the user [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson) [in the user data directory](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations). If using a [profile](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/profiles), then by the profile's settings.json file.
  - Workspace folder settings go in the .vscode/settings.json file, and workspace settings (when using multi-root workspaces) go in the workspace's .code-workspace file. See also [the related user docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_workspace-settingsjson-location).
- Configuration has a "scope" ([API docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#ConfigurationScope)), which can be a specific resource, or a language, or both, or a text document, or a workspace folder. For the language scope, see [the related user docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_language-specific-editor-settings).

---

> Could it be an extension?

Depends what you mean. Extensions can *internally* do whatever they want with how they use their own contributed settings (use default values that they don't specify in their extension manifest, or disregard the value the user sets altogether), but if they write to a setting value through [the extension API for settings values (see `WorkspaceConfiguration.update(...)`)](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#WorkspaceConfiguration), VS Code will know.

---

> Could it be some non-settings.json configuration file?

See above. Though also, extensions can have their own types of configuration files that VS Code itself doesn't know or care about (and if the setting change is done there, then VS Code itself will not know), while still having parallel/related settings that VS Code *does* know about. Such as [the C/C++ extension's c_cpp_properties.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference), for which defaults can be set via VS Code settings, or tsconfig/jsconfig files, for which some compiler/type-checking options can be defaulted via the `js/ts.implicitProjectConfig.*` settings, etc.

---

> Could this merely mean another project modifies it in its Workspace settings?

If you mean a workspace / workspace folder that is not the currently open one, no. VS Code will not show the modified indicator for that (and thank goodness it doesn't).